# Output multiple command results to a single TXT file

Tags: powershell, text, output, multiline

Im pretty new to Powershell, and have worked out a few commands that I need to run that will provide me a very simple form of a report on the status of a system. I will be building more commands on to this to create a more detailed report later. I have the below code that seems to write the actual text but to the resultant of the command. I was wondering if anyone knew a way to do the above.

```
$health = {"Sys Techout" 
"==========================" 
"" 
"Run at:" 
date 
"" 
"Command: systeminfo" 
"===================" 
systeminfo 
"" 
"Command: query session" 
"======================" 
query session /counter 
"" 
"Command: query user" 
"===================" 
query user 
"" 

"Command: Listening WinRM port check" 
"=================================" 
netstat -an | findstr LISTENING | findstr :598[56] 
"" }

$health | Out-File -append c:\Systech\Health2.txt -NoClobber
```

The above code ideal should do the following

1. Write the results to a text file in the location **C:\Systech\Helath2.txt**.
2. Set the title in the contents to Sys Techout
3. Write each sub heading (Command: systeminfo) and the next
   line should be the results of the command. and so on for each
   command thats added.

After writing the above i just get raw text and no results in the text. Any help would be great.

Hari

Comment: Do each thing individually outputting the results to the file and appending.

Comment: `$health | Out-File ...` -> `& $health | Out-File ...`

Answer (score 0):

You're very close  to the  solution. Just put `&` at the beginning of the last line to invoke the scriptblock in `$health` as in:

```
& $health | Out-File -append c:\Systech\Health2.txt -NoClobber
```